# Tkinter Command Lambda Function Modify Variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, tkinter

My application is a form which populates its fields from a database. I am in the process of writing the function that navigates between these records.
I am having problems writing my "next record" function.

At any given time, the "Current Record" showing on the screen is in a variable `current_record`.

```
def next_record(current_record):
    current_index = current_record.index
    current_record = Competitor(competitors[current_index + 1], current_index + 1)
    print(current_record.index)
    populate_form(current_record)
```

And my button calling this function:

```
action_button_6 = tkinter.Button(group_buttons, text='>>', width=5,
                                 command=lambda: next_record(current_record))
```

Although the function does its job and loads the new record into the form, it does not reassign "current_record" to the new competitor as show in the third line of the function.

How can I modify the variable from within this function?

Comment: `current_record` in `next_record` is local variable and it have nothing to do with `current_record` in `lambda`. If you assign new element to `current_record` in `next_record` you lose contact with original record.

Comment: I know I have made life a little bit more difficult for myself by naming them all the same. My question is how can I modify the variable passed to the function in lambda?

Comment: You have to change valued in existing element if you can - like `current_record.some_variable = competitors[current_index + 1]` and `current_record.index = current_index + 1`.

Comment: so change the index of the current instance and then execute some internal class function to re-initialise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you **explicitly declare** a variable that you modify in a function global, it defaults to being local **even if there is a global variable with the same name**, thus `current_record` is a local variable. Adding `global current_record` to the beginning of the `next_record` function and renaming the function argument to `old_record` would fix that.