# How to use a global variable in Python?

Tags: python

I'm not sure why it's not working when I declare a global variable...

```
first_read = True

def main():

    if (first_read == True):
        print "hello world"
        first_read = False

    print 'outside of if statement'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

My traceback shows the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "true.py", line 12, in <module>
      main()   
   File "true.py", line 5, in main
     if (first_read == True): 
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'first_read' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tkinter Command Lambda Function Modify Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33972893/tkinter-command-lambda-function-modify-variable)

Answer (score 3):

You have to define variable as global:

```
first_read = True

def main():
    global first_read
    if (first_read == True):
       print "hello world"
       first_read = False

    print 'outside of if statement'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Just curious... I also have a global variable: 'ntw_device = []' declared.. But I didn't have to specify global ntw_device to use it... Why is that? Is it different for lists?

Answer (score 2):

In `def main` you should declare a global variable like this:

```
global first_read
```

this will use `first_read` as global variable in main function.